# Connect GitHub repo with AppCenter for CI/CD

Tags: github, continuous-integration, visual-studio-app-center, continuous-delivery

First of all I would like to mention that this repo is not created by me, it is owned by another team which I was given **admin** privilege. Here is the image:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to connect this repo to MS App Center. However I don't see this repo in the list of available repos to connect. Here is the image:

[image]

Steps:

1. Go to **Marketplace**
2. Search for **App Center** and click on it (It is already downloaded)
3. Click on **configure access** (redirected to https://github.com/settings/installations)
4. Press on **configure**
5. Go to **Repository access** section and select **Only select repositories** to add my new repo

Here on the last step on trying to search for **frontend** keyword of my repo I was granted access to, however I don't see it in the list.

How can I find and connect it to App Center?